# Navigating to folder structure of remote server

Tags: unc, ssis

I am aware that this is a really simple question and maybe that's why I haven't found a simple and concise answer.

My task is the following: I am using SSIS to connect to a remote server and save some files to it.

The question is the following:

The UNC path

```
\\Server
```

in which absolute path does it correspond to?

If I want to save my files in C:\Program Files for example, whould that be

```
\\Server\Program Files
```

?

Comment: Are you talking about accessing the remote server's shared folders? If so, you should share a folder and the access it with `\\server\folder` or use the administrative `c$` share so in your case you could visit `\\server\c$\Program files`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding my previous comment into an answer.

You can [create](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770880(v=ws.11).aspx) a Windows Shared folder on the remote machine, sharing e.g. `C:\Program Files` with the name e.g. `folder`. It will then be possible to access it remotely as `\\Server\folder`.

Or, you can make use of the administrative shares `c$`, `d$`and so on to access any file on drives, respectively, `c`, `d`, etc. In your case, you would visit `\\Server\c$\Program Files` in order to access `C:\Program Files` on the remote machine called `Server`.